# Coldfusion CFC defined in {} shorthand behaving weirdly

Tags: rest, coldfusion, cfc

Weird behavior of cfc defined using shorthand:

```
component {
    remote string function get() httpmethod="GET" returnformat="plain" {
    return "hello world";
    }
}
```

compared to expected behavior defined this way:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="get" access="remote" returntype="String" httpmethod="GET">
        <cfreturn "hello world">
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

The 2nd example called as a REST service correctly returns hello world

The 1st example however returns hello world but ALSO appends the entire component's .cfc code as follows:

`hello worldcomponent { remote string function get() { return "hello world"; } }`

Any ideas anybody what could be causing this? I'm stumped. Thks

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Comment: I wondering if you just wrap the first one in `<cfscript></cfscript>` if that would help

Comment: What web server are you using? It seems like the web server is just giving you the contents of the file. Doesn't explain how you got the function output though?

Comment: Discovered a fix by moving this:      <cfinclude template="#arguments.TargetPage#" /> from <cffunction name="onRequestStart"> of Application.CFC to <cffunction name="onRequest">. Don't fully understand why. Weird behavior only exhibited on a new hosting server. Both examples work fine on my local dev installation

Comment: Coldfusion 2018. IIS web server